# Problem connecting DBeaver to Apache Ignite Database server, handshake failed

Tags: ignite, dbeaver

I am new to apache-ignite DB and Dbeaver. I was trying to connect to existing apache-ignite DB from newly downloaded DBeaver IDE.

1. First you have to choose the type of DB connection (you are given option to choose, like PostGre, Apache-ignite, etc) in my case I choose apache-ignite.
2. On next step, you have to fill the address of your DB (it is written localhost by default, in my case DB is on remote server, so I filled in IP address of the server) and also 10800 port (as it's standart).
   also I filled in the username and password  for DB.
3. After these I pressed Test connection and got this kind of error :

   Handshake failed [driverProtocolVer=ClientListenerProtocolVersion [major=2, minor=9, maintenance=0], remoteNodeProtocolVer=ClientListenerProtocolVersion [major=2, minor=8, maintenance=2], err=Unsupported version.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that apache-ignite driver on your computer and on database claster are different. In my case, my local version 2.9.0 was higher than claster's version  2.8.2.
I had to downgrade my version locally to be able to connect to DB.
Drivers can be downloaded from   [official website](https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi) of apache-ignite.
After you download and install drivers, go to your connection in DBeaver and follow steps:

1. Edit Connection
2. Edit Driver settings
3. Add new files of downloaded correct driver version manually, with Add File

Test connection

Comment: DBeaver should be able to download drivers from Maven repository on its own.

Comment: DBeaver is able, but it will download the latest possible version. In this case, the version of driver had to be lower than the Claster's  driver version

Comment: DBeaver actually lets you type in specific artifact version in driver settings, and then re-download.

Comment: Probably I have not found this option, good to know. Thank you !